# Python Graph/Sensor data

Tags: python

i have an arduino that sends a text file to my computer through a python socket, im not sure what is causing the problem im having, my python socket script runs in a loop with the help of a batch script that keeps it running. the problem is sometimes i get a blank text file when receiving the txt file from the arduino. im not sure if its a damaged transfer/connection or the arduinos code. the final problem ends up being my matplotlib graph plot crashes when it gets to the blank spot in the log because it has no value to log just the line number. heres the python upload server script,

```
with open('sensData.txt','wb') as f:
while True:
t = conn.recv(20)
print t
if t =='':
   s.close()
   break     

f.write(t)
```

here is the part of the arduino code that uploads the file,

```
void ftransfer() {
char rbuffer[2]; 
char c;
int n; // open test file
SdFile rdfile("sensData.txt", O_READ); // <--- Name of file to be transfered
uint32_t fsize; //Obtain file size
fsize = rdfile.fileSize() - rdfile.curPosition();
Serial.println(fsize);
if (!rdfile.isOpen()) error("File could not be opened, check 
configuration...");  // check for open error
 Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
 Serial.println("Connecting 10.0.0.89 To Open Transfer...");
 Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
 if (client.connect(server1, localport)) {
 Serial.println("Connected");   // if you get a connection, report back via 
 serial:
    while ((n = rdfile.fgets(rbuffer, sizeof(rbuffer))) > 0) {
     client.write(rbuffer, sizeof(rbuffer) - 1);
   }
  client.stop();
 }
else {
Serial.println("No upload server available");     // No response from 
server1
 }
 }
```

heres the arduino part that reads the sensor,

```
void loop(void) {
tempvalue = analogRead(tempsensor);

mySensorData = sd.open("sensData.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (mySensorData) {
Serial.print("Analyzing  Reading "); //Print Your results
delay(5000); //Pause between readings.
mySensorData.println (tempvalue);
mySensorData.close();
ftransfer();
delay(1000);
sd.remove("sensData.txt");
Serial.println("Done");//close the file
}
}
```

here the part of my python script that updates the log file for the graph,

```
 def Log(self):
     with open('sensData.txt') as f: 
        FILE2 = f.read()

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
     if self.LogUpdate == 1:
        t = threading.Timer(1, self.Log) #every 45 minutes
        t.start()
        #print "disabled"
     if self.LogUpdate == 0:  
        p = open( 'sens-Data-Log.txt', 'a' ) #(w= write)(a= 
        p.write(str(self.count) + ' ' + FILE2 + '\n')
        print "itworks"
        self.count+=1
        #print self.count
        p.close()
        t = threading.Timer(5, self.Log) #every 45 minutes
        t.start()
```

i need help figuring out what i can do here to prevent an upload of a blank sensData.txt file, and what can i do if the python script receives a corrupted/blank transfer? even if i have to have python input a false value of 0.0 that would atleast keep my program from crashing. i was leaning more towards making the python scrip not write to the log if the sens-Data-txt file is blank?

think i figured it out by doing this,

```
  def Log(self):
     with open('sensData.txt') as f: 
        FILE2 = f.read()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
     if FILE2 =="":
        print "Text File Was Blank !!"
        t = threading.Timer(3, self.Log) #every 45 minutes
        t.start()
        return
```